# Return a list if entries who exist and not exist

Tags: mysql, exists

I have a list of network-devices in a database-table. Users can get misc information about those devices using a web-interface (ends up in the query as `WHERE hostname IN('hostname1','hostname2',...)`). Let's say one of the five given entries is wrong because of a misspelling. So normally i get four answers from the database-query, the wrong one will be still ignored. I need to detect that not existing entry to give the user a hint like:

```
hostname1 exist -> requested Information
hostname2 exist -> requested Information
hostname3 NOT EXIST
hostname4 exist -> requested Information
hostname5 exist -> requested Information
```

I ran out of ideas with the EXISTS Option. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. This would normally belong in application logic.

Comment: All things are possible, but yes this would normally be handled in application code

Answer (score 0):

I find only one solution after create a temporary table "search", suppose to containts one column named "hostname" with value. I do not find a way to convert a list of values ('hostname1' , 'hostname2', 'hostname4') into a list of record. So a temporary table of one column here:

table "search" column "hostname"

```
hostname1
hostname2
hostname4
```

Here the creation of the "search" table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS search AS  SELECT 'hostname1' as hostname from host union SELECT 'hostname2' as hostname  from host union  select 'hostname4' as hostname  from host
```

Then a left join on a column:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS search AS  SELECT 'hostname1' as hostname from host union SELECT 'hostname2' as hostname  from host union  select 'hostname4' as hostname  from host; select * from search left join host ON host.hostname = search.hostname;
```

This is the output columns (hostname,id,hostname):

```
hostname1   1   hostname1   
hostname2   2   hostname2   
hostname4   NULL    NULL
```

In my case, hostname4 does not exist into the initial table host so that a way to detect an incorrect value with the id column of the result for example.